# Copy text to Clipboard

Tags: c#, clipboard

I am doing C#/.NET app. I want to make a button on toolbar that will basically invoke Ctrl+C (copy to clipboard). I looked to Clipboard class, but problem is since I have multiple textboxes on form, I would need to scan which one has focus and if/is selected text, in order to select text from it etc., so I think there must me “one-liner” solution.

Any ideas?

(Also, how to add all 3: Cut, Copy, Paste to toolbar, under same conditions- multiple tekstboxes on main form..)

Comment: Windows Forms? Or WPF?

Comment: Note that if you have button it will take focus away from text boxes... Depending on what you want it may be more user friendly to associate "copy to clipboard" button with some/each textbox.

Comment: Basically he has to save the last focused `TextBox` and copy its text when `Button` is clicked

Comment: If he is using WinForms he could simply set the ShortcutsEnabled Property to true

Comment: Can I invoke shortcut from toolbox-click-handler?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: If for Winforms..

Place this in your invoke function:

```
Clipboard.SetText(ActiveControl.Text);
```

As mentioned below by Daniel Abou Chleih: If you have to interact with a control to invoke the function the focus
will be changed to that control. This only works if you call it through other means.

**Edit**:
Not a one-liner but works on the last active TextBox:

```
private Control lastInputControl { get; set; }
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    // WM_SETFOCUS fired.
    if (m.Msg == 0x0007)
    {
        if (ActiveControl is TextBox)
        {
            lastInputControl = ActiveControl;
        }
    }

    // Process the message so that ActiveControl might change.
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (ActiveControl is TextBox && lastInputControl != ActiveControl)
    {
        lastInputControl = ActiveControl;
    }
}

public void CopyActiveText()
{
        if (lastInputControl == null) return;
        Clipboard.SetText(lastInputControl.Text);
}
```

Now you can call CopyActiveText() to get the most recent TextBox that lost focus last or currently has focus.

Comment: But when he clicks the button, textboxes are loosing focus. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're right. The active control changes before the click event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WinForms I possibly have a small Solution for that problem.

Create an Object to store your last selected TextBox

```
TextBox lastSelectedTextBox = null;
```

In your Constructor create an Eventhandler for each `TextBox` in your `Form` for the `GotFocus`-Event by calling the `AddGotFocusEventHandler`-Method with the parameter `this.Controls`.

```
public void AddGotFocusEventHandler(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in controls)
    {
        if(ctrl is TextBox)
            ctrl.GotFocus += ctrl_GotFocus;

        AddGotFocusEventHandler(ctrl.Controls);
    }
}
```

And set the `lastSelectedTextBox` to your currently selected TextBox

```
void c_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox selectedTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    lastSelectedTextBox = selectedTextBox;
}
```

In your Click-EventHandler for the button check if selectedText is null and copy the text to clipboard:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lastSelectedTextBox.SelectedText))
       Clipboard.SetText(lastSelectedTextBox.Text);
    else
       Clipboard.SetText(lastSelectedTextBox.SelectedText);
}
```

Comment: this.Controls will only return controls on the form. Not it's subcontrols.