# copy text in clipboard

Tags: c#, clipboard

i need the selected text in my textBox to be copied in my **clipboard** by my **MenuItemCopy()** methode and then be able to paste it by  **MenuItemPaste()**.need some help with it.
here is my codes:

```
    private void goToToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void menuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;

        switch (menuItem.Name.Replace("ToolStripMenuItem", ""))
        {

            case "copy":
                MenuItemCopy();
                break;
            case "paste":
                MenuItemPaste();
                break;

        }
    } 
    private void MenuItemPaste()
    {

    }

    private void MenuItemCopy()
    {

    }
```

i tried    string  str= Clipboard.GetText()  but it did not work.what is the problem?

Comment: A simple search would give you tons of answers. Like this one on this same site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499728/copy-text-to-clipboard?rq=1

Comment: i checked the link it wasnt that much helpful in my case..but tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Clipboard` class ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and `SelectedText` property of `TextBox` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectedtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

To copy data to the clipboard use the `SetText` method ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydby206k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

To get data from the clipboard use the `GetText` method ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz40084e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

The following code allows you to copy selected text from `TextBox` to clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetText(tbText.SelectedText);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Clipboard.SetText("Hello, clipboard");
```

To copy the contents of a textbox:

```
  Clipboard.SetText(txtClipboard.Text);
```

To get the content in Clipboard

```
    string  str= Clipboard.GetText()
```

Answer (score 1):

To set some sort of text in the clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetText("Whatever you want");
```

So in yourcase

```
Clipboard.SetText(txtMyTextBox.Text);
```

To get it back, use

```
Clipboard.GetText();
```

So

```
txtMyTextBox.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)