# Clipboard label copy selected content only issue

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have follow below example to copy **Label** selected text using Clipboard but its copying full content not selected text. Is there a way to copy part of the text and paste in a label in xamarin.

[copy text in clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302195/copy-text-in-clipboard)

Comment: [Edit] your question and add your code so that we're able to see how you've implemented it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use custom renderer.

I follow the steps in the blog. https://medium.com/@HeikkiDev/selectable-label-on-xamarin-forms-9b050267bf8e

MyLabel.cs

```
 public class MyLabel : View
{
public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(MyLabel), default(string));
public static readonly BindableProperty TextColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TextColor), typeof(Color), typeof(MyLabel), Color.Black);
public static readonly BindableProperty FontAttributesProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FontAttributes), typeof(FontAttributes), typeof(MyLabel), FontAttributes.None);
public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FontSize), typeof(double), typeof(MyLabel), -1.0);

public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}

public Color TextColor
{
    get { return (Color)GetValue(TextColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextColorProperty, value); }
}

public FontAttributes FontAttributes
{
    get { return (FontAttributes)GetValue(FontAttributesProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FontAttributesProperty, value); }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
public double FontSize
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
}
}
```

MyLabelRenderer.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyLabel), typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace LabelDemo.Droid
{
 public class MyLabelRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyLabel, TextView>
{
  TextView textView;

public MyLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
{

}

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyLabel> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    var label = (MyLabel)Element;
    if (label == null)
        return;

    if (Control == null)
    {
        textView = new TextView(this.Context);
    }

    textView.Enabled = true;
    textView.Focusable = true;
    textView.LongClickable = true;
    textView.SetTextIsSelectable(true);

    // Initial properties Set
    textView.Text = label.Text;
    textView.SetTextColor(label.TextColor.ToAndroid());
    switch (label.FontAttributes)
    {
        case FontAttributes.None:
            textView.SetTypeface(null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            break;
        case FontAttributes.Bold:
            textView.SetTypeface(null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold);
            break;
        case FontAttributes.Italic:
            textView.SetTypeface(null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Italic);
            break;
        default:
            textView.SetTypeface(null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            break;
    }

    textView.TextSize = (float)label.FontSize;

    SetNativeControl(textView);
 }

protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName == MyLabel.TextProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        if (Control != null && Element != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Element.Text))
        {
            textView.Text = Element.Text;
        }
    }
    else if (e.PropertyName == MyLabel.TextColorProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        if (Control != null && Element != null)
        {
            textView.SetTextColor(Element.TextColor.ToAndroid());
        }
    }
    else if (e.PropertyName == MyLabel.FontAttributesProperty.PropertyName
                || e.PropertyName == MyLabel.FontSizeProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        if (Control != null && Element != null)
        {
            switch (Element.FontAttributes)
            {
                case FontAttributes.None:
                    textView.SetTypeface(null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                    break;
                case FontAttributes.Bold:
                    textView.SetTypeface(null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Bold);
                    break;
                case FontAttributes.Italic:
                    textView.SetTypeface(null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Italic);
                    break;
                default:
                    textView.SetTypeface(null, Android.Graphics.TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                    break;
            }

            textView.TextSize = (float)Element.FontSize;
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

MainPage.xml

```
<StackLayout>
<local:MyLabel
    FontAttributes="Bold"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    Text="This text can be selected!"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check Below link. I think it's solve your problem

http://blog.rawatchetan.com/xamarin-forms-custom-label-to-copy-text/